# How do I get CSS to apply to dynamically created elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to dynamically create seat options for a theater app but the CSS isn't being applied to my  tag. Not sure why

Here is the relevant CSS that I'm trying to apply to the code. I have tested with the code created non-dynamically and the CSS applies, but when I use the for loop to generate the  tags the styling is not applied.

```js
const number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
const section1 = document.getElementById('section1');

for (var j = 0; j < number.length; j++) {
  console.log(number[j]);

  const a = document.createElement("a")
  const text = `B ${number[j]}`;

  a.append(text);

  section1.append(a);
}
```

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.column {
  width: 49.5%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.column a {
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background: rgb(91, 224, 247);
  margin: 7px 0;
  cursor: crosshair;
}

a {
  font-family: cursive;
  ;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" id="section1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the CSS?

Comment: @epascarello I just made an edit to include the CSS

Comment: okay so does one of the ancestors have the column class?

Comment: @epascarello Yes, it's being dropped into a div with the class of "column"

Comment: Well I just made it runnable.... so what is different? Works fine here.

Comment: Did you test this code specifically, as-is? I just typed it into a blank web page and it seems to work fine. If you're dealing with shadow DOM or across frames or by embedding documents, styles may get applied differently.